# SQL | Set Default Value of Column While Fetching SEQUELIZE ORM

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to set default value while Fetching data from DB using Sequelize ORM. For example I have some SQL query like

```
 SELECT a.affiliate_id, a.active AS current_state,       
IF(MAX(cn.contract_id) IS NULL ,0, IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(),MAX(cn.contract_date)) > 60,0,1)) AS affiliate_active       

FROM zn_pf_affiliate a       

LEFT JOIN zn_clients c ON a.affiliate_id = c.refferal_id AND c.refferal_type = 'affiliate'       

LEFT JOIN zn_internal_inquiries i ON c.clientid = i.clientID       

LEFT JOIN zn_pf_contracts cn ON i.inquiry_id = cn.source_object_id AND cn.source_object_type = 'lead' AND cn.stage=3 AND cn.status=3       

WHERE a.agency_id = 159297       

GROUP BY a.affiliate_id       

HAVING current_state <> affiliate_active;
```

I want to convert this with Sequelize ORM but the main problem is     `IF(MAX(cn.contract_id) IS NULL ,0, IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(),MAX(cn.contract_date)) > 60,0,1)) AS affiliate_active` How I write this line in Sequelize ORM. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use some SQL pieces in Sequelize query you need to use `Sequelize.literal` like this:

```js
const items = Model.findAll({
  attributes: [
   ...// other attributes,
   [Sequelize.literal('(IF(MAX(cn.contract_id) IS NULL ,0, IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(),MAX(cn.contract_date)) > 60,0,1)))', 'affiliate_active']
],
... // other options
})
```